# Need help when using composition in a class

Tags: c++

I have a class named Package that contains objects from a `Address` class as private data members. There are other classes but I didn't show them since they aren't necessary. The **address.h** and cpp files were provided to me and I can't change them.

My problem is in the **Package.cpp file (line 5)** where I need to initialize the Address objects because I'm using composition but I don't know how to do it. I know I need to explicitly call the overloaded constructor of the address class but I'm not sure how. When I put `:Address` after the package constructor I immediately get an error saying `Address` is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class `Package`.

**Address.h**

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_H
#define ADDRESS_H

#include <string>

class Address
{
public:
   // constructor initializes data members
   Address( const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::string &, int );
   virtual ~Address() { } // virtual destructor

   void setName( const std::string & );     // set name
   std::string getName() const;             // return name
   void setAddress( const std::string & );  // set street address
   std::string getAddress() const;          // return street address
   void setCity( const std::string & );     // set city
   std::string getCity() const;             // return city
   void setState( const std::string & );    // set state
   std::string getState() const;            // return state
   void setZIP( int );                      // set sZIP code
   int getZIP() const;                      // return ZIP code
   void print() const;                      //print the data members

private:
   // data members to store sender and recipient's address information
   std::string name;
   std::string streetAddress;
   std::string city;
   std::string state;
   int ZIP;
};

#endif
```

**Asssign3.cpp**

```
// Assign3.cpp
// Processing Packages polymorphically.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "Package.h"          // Package class definition
#include "TwoDayPackage.h"    // TwoDayPackage class definition
#include "OvernightPackage.h" // OvernightPackage class definition
#include "Address.h"          // Address class definition
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create vector packages
    vector < Package * > packages( 3 );

    //create to and from address for the three objects
    Address add1To("Lou Brown", "1 Main St", "Boston", "MA", 11111);
    Address add1From("Mary Smith", "7 Elm St", "New York", "NY", 22222);

    Address add2To("Lisa Klein", "5 Broadway Rd", "Indianapolis", "IN", 33333);
    Address add2From("Bob George", "21 Pine Rd", "Miami", "FL", 44444);

    Address add3to("Ed Lewis", "2 Oak St", "Boston", "MA", 55555);
    Address add3From("Don Kelly", "9 Main St", "Denver", "CO", 66666);

    // initialize vector with Packages
    packages[ 0 ] = new Package(add1To, add1From, 8.5, .5 );
    packages[ 1 ] = new TwoDayPackage(add2To , add2From, 10.5, .65, 2.0 );
    packages[ 2 ] = new OvernightPackage(add3to , add3From, 12.25, .7, .25 );

    cout << fixed << setprecision( 2 );
    // print each package's information and cost
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < packages.size(); i++ ) 
    {
        cout << "PACKAGE " << i + 1 << "\n";
        packages[i]->print();         

        double cost = packages[ i ]->calculateCost();
        cout << "\nShipping Cost: $" << cost << "\n\n";
    } 
}
```

**Package.cpp ERROR HERE**

```
#include "Package.h"
#include "Address.h"

Package::Package(Address gets, Address sends, double weight, double costPerOunce)
{ // error no default constructor for class "Address" 
    double weight = weight;
    double costPerOunce = costPerOunce;
}

double Package::getWeight()const
{
    return weight;
}
```

**Package.h**

```
#ifndef PACKAGE_H
#define PACKAGE_H
#include "Address.h"

class Package
{
public:
    Package(Address recipient, Address sender, double weight, double costPerOunce);
    virtual ~Package();

    double getWeight()const;
    virtual void print() const;
    double calculateCost()const;

private:
    Address recipient;
    Address sender;
    double weight;
    double costPerOunce;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Post your code directly, rather than linking please.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `Address` members and as the error states that class does not have a default constructor. Therefore, you need to initialize your 2 `Address` class members.

```
Package::Package(Address gets, Address sends, double weight, double costPerOunce) :
    recipient(gets),
    sender(sends),
    weight(weight),
    costPerOunce(costPerOunce)
{
    // I'm guessing you want to set your class members instead of these local variables...    
    //double weight = weight;
    //double costPerOunce = costPerOunce;
}
```

Unrelated but you probably want to use `const Address&` as the type for your construct parameters.

The `:` portion is called the [iniatializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).